# How can I use a method without any page transition or any reboot app

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm currently developing an application using SwiftUI.

I want to use a method when a view appears.

In the case of the code I attached below, I can use the `print` method when the app is booted and done some transitions between pages.

---

But I want to use the `print` method when I reopen the app like below:

- 1: run the code on a simulator (I can see the `print` method works).
- 2: press a home button.
- 3: open the app with tap the app icon (I can't see the `print` method works ).

  (*) I want to use the `print` method here.

How can I do it as I want in this case?

[image]

---

here is the code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var selection = 0
 
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selection){
            Text("First View")
                .onAppear(){
                    print("First")
            }
                .tabItem {
                        Text("First")
                }
                .tag(0)
            
            Text("Second View")
                .tabItem {
                        Text("Second")
                }
                .tag(1)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

---

**ADD:**

I found a way to use some function when the app becomes a foreground from a background using `sceneWillEnterForeground` or `sceneWillResignActive` in `SceneDelegate.swift`

But in this case, when the app becomes a foreground with the SecondView also works function.
And I want to modify the code to work the function only when the app becomes foreground with the FirstView.

Is there any way to do that?

SceneDelegate.swift

```
func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
        print("BecomeActive")
    }
func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene) {
        print("Foreground")
    }
```

---

Xcode: Version 11.7

Swift: Swift 5

Comment: The fact that application goes into background (when you tap Home button) does not mean that view disappeared - it is still there (the same as cmd-tab on macOS) - it is changed application state. So you need to handle different events with same handler. And app active/inactive/background is handled in SceneDelegate (in your case).

Comment: @Asperi , Thank you for your comment, is there any way instead of using `onAppear` method in this case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use an `@EnvironmentObject` to track the application state (by observing notifications):

```
class AppState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isActive = true

    private var observers = [NSObjectProtocol]()

    init() {
        observers.append(
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil, queue: .main) { _ in
                self.isActive = true
            }
        )
        observers.append(
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification, object: nil, queue: .main) { _ in
                self.isActive = false
            }
        )
    }
    
    deinit {
        observers.forEach(NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver)
    }
}
```

You need to create this (once only) in the SceneDelegate and pass to the ContentView as an `@EnvironmentObject`:

```
let appState = AppState()
let contentView = ContentView().environmentObject(appState)
```

Now you can use the `@EnvironmentObject` in any view you want:

```
struct FirstView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var appState: AppState

    var body: some View {
        Text("First View, isActive: \(appState.isActive.description)")
    }
}
```