# Handling close and terminate app events (SwiftUI)

Tags: swift, event-handling, swiftui

How can I handle close and terminate app events in SwiftUI?

```
View
{
    ...
}.onDisappear {
    //My code
}
```

Working only when I change view, not when I close or terminate my app.

Comment: I refer to beta software, so I am not allowed to provide any information on SO, but if you're using the new `App` and `Scene` protocols with `WindowGroup` container, then it is as presented in this Apple Developer Forum question titled ["Using Core Data with SwiftUI App Protocol"](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/650876) and [my answer](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/650876?answerId=620207022#620207022)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `UIApplication.willTerminateNotification`:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIApplication.willTerminateNotification, object: nil, queue: .main) { _ in
    // terminating
}
```

This answer may explain better how to use it in SwiftUI:

- [How can I use a method without any page transition or any reboot app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63765784/8697793)

Comment: This also works with `NSApplication.willTerminateNotification` if you are writing a Mac app.

Comment: I had a hard time implementing an async func it looks like we only have about 5 seconds to do whatever we need and return. 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623111-applicationwillterminate

Answer (score 13):

You should use .onReceive modifier and Subscribe to the notification you want like this:

```
YourView()
    .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.willTerminateNotification), perform: { output in
        // Code to run on will terminate
    })
```

You can use UIApplicationDelegate notifications and UIScene notifications

Docs:

- [UIApplicationDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate)
- [UIScene](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscene)

Comment: This does **not** get called on a view inside a `WindowGroup`, `WindowGroup { ContentView(). onReceive ...`

Comment: `NSApplication.willTerminateNotification` works on `WindowGroup`, ***however*** at least 1 window instance needs to be still open for it to trigger. If all windows are clossed and the app is quit/terminated, it does not trigger.

Answer (score 2):

This work when you swipe up and close the app right away, but when you go to home screen and the close the app is not called.

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {

func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
       print("End App")
   }
```